# List of string to element

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings like this:

```
L=['[1,2,3]','[3,4,5,6]','[9,8,7]']
```

I want to make a list of list elements like this:

```
Y=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5,6],[9,8,7]]
```

How can I do it in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate each string as a python literal within a list comprehension

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> [literal_eval(i) for i in L]
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [9, 8, 7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Every element of your array is a valid JSON so you could do

```
import json

Y = [json.loads(l) for l in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this manually:

```
>>> L=['[1,2,3]','[3,4,5,6]','[9,8,7]'] 
>>> [[int(x) for x in l[1:-1].split(',')] for l in L]
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [9, 8, 7]]
```

Or without `split()`, as suggested by @Moinuddin Quadri in the comments:

```
>>> [[int(x) for x in l[1:-1:2]] for l in L]
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5, 6], [9, 8, 7]]
```

Comment: or `[[int(x) for x in l[1:-1:2]] for l in L]` without using split. (+1)